# How to "Track Changes" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

"Track Changes" is a very useful feature in Word, but I can't find a similar button in Excel. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that describes how it works in MS Excel 2007.  http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/track-changes-in-excel/  It should be as easy as going to Tools -> Track changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

[image]